# Open a page from a smartphone on a raspberry pi 3

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to open an HTML/CSS/JavaScript webpage that is on my rasp. My raspberry is not going to be connected to the internet but I want to access  the webpage from a smartphone.

Apache is not going to work because my pi is offline. And I need to stay offline (because i use a local JSON that is continually modified by a Python script).

So I want to create something like a hotspot to access the pi and open this local page.

Everything I found doesn't work because all need an internet connection. Obviously for the installation I have an internet connection (wifi but not Ethernet).

Comment: You could check [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which allows you to expose your `localhost`? Not sure if that helps though?

Comment: Your problem is described in a strange way. You need a network connection between raspberry pi and a smartphone. Apache should be configured to listen on an interface that is used to communicate with the smartphone.

Comment: Yes obviously, but the rasp is not going to be connected to internet. It will have the task of a hotspot but NOT connected to Internet. I just want to display one page host on the pi from the smartphone when i connect myself to the pi with Wifi. You understand ?... Sorry if it's not clear...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your RaspberryPi as an WLAN-AccessPoint and then bind Apache to the WiFi interface.

Setting the RaspberryPi up as an access point: [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)

Apache Binding: [Binding-Apache](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/q20206/bind.html)